# Elasticsearch Synonyms returning 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I created a synonym filter named "synonym_filter"

```
"synonym_filter": {
                 "type": "synonym",
                 "synonyms": [
                    "adidas, xyz, abc",
                    "nike, rofl, lol"
                 ]
              }
```

and analyzer named "synonyms"

```
 "synonyms": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym_filter"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
```

according to the elasticsearch documentation. The complete settings now look like this.

```
GET /test6_de_idx1/_settings

   "test6_de_idx1": {
  "settings": {
     "index": {
        "creation_date": "1471372087742",
        "analysis": {
           "filter": {
              "edge_ngram_back": {
                 "min_gram": "2",
                 "side": "back",
                 "type": "edgeNGram",
                 "max_gram": "10"
              },
              "edge_ngram_front": {
                 "min_gram": "2",
                 "side": "front",
                 "type": "edgeNGram",
                 "max_gram": "10"
              },
              "synonym_filter": {
                 "type": "synonym",
                 "synonyms": [
                    "adidas, xyz, abc",
                    "nike, rofl, lol"
                 ]
              },
              "stop": {
                 "type": "stop",
                 "stopwords": "_german_"
              },
              "strip_hyphens": {
                 "pattern": "-",
                 "type": "pattern_replace",
                 "replacement": ""
              },
              "length": {
                 "type": "length",
                 "min": "2"
              },
              "strip_spaces": {
                 "pattern": "\\s",
                 "type": "pattern_replace",
                 "replacement": ""
              },
              "snowball": {
                 "type": "snowball",
                 "language": "German"
              },
              "strip_dots": {
                 "pattern": "\\.",
                 "type": "pattern_replace",
                 "replacement": ""
              }
           },
           "analyzer": {
              "std": {
                 "filter": [
                    "standard",
                    "elision",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "stop",
                    "length"
                 ],
                 "char_filter": "html_strip",
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              "synonyms": {
                 "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym_filter"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              "keyword_suffix": {
                 "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "strip_spaces",
                    "strip_dots",
                    "strip_hyphens",
                    "edge_ngram_back"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
              "text_suffix": {
                 "filter": [
                    "standard",
                    "elision",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "stop",
                    "edge_ngram_back"
                 ],
                 "char_filter": "html_strip",
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              "language": {
                 "filter": [
                    "standard",
                    "elision",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "stop",
                    "snowball",
                    "length"
                 ],
                 "char_filter": "html_strip",
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              "keyword": {
                 "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "strip_spaces",
                    "strip_dots",
                    "strip_hyphens"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
              "keyword_prefix": {
                 "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "strip_spaces",
                    "strip_dots",
                    "strip_hyphens",
                    "edge_ngram_front"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
              "text_prefix": {
                 "filter": [
                    "standard",
                    "elision",
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase",
                    "stop",
                    "edge_ngram_front"
                 ],
                 "char_filter": "html_strip",
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              }
           }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "sAiM27R2QOKLj9wjrwoAqw",
        "version": {
           "created": "2030399"
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Testing the analyzer with

```
GET /test6_de_idx1/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "synonyms",
  "text" : "xyz is the English queen"
}
```

shows that the analyzer is working:

```
"tokens": [
      {
         "token": "xyz",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "adidas",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "abc",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "is",
         "start_offset": 4,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "the",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "english",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 18,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "queen",
         "start_offset": 19,
         "end_offset": 24,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
```

But when i do a test search with a synonym I get 0 results with adidas, which is used in data i get results.

```
GET /test6_de_idx1/_search?q=xyz&size=5



 "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
```

What could please be the problem?

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick reply! A hit looks like this for search term "adidas":

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test6_de_idx1",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "59279",
            "_score": 1.0859994,
            "_source": {
               "id": 59279,
               "sku": "0002-10780",
               "type_id": "configurable",
               "brand": "Adidas",
               "color": "Mehrfarbig",
               "manufacturer": "Adidas",
               "material": "Polyester",
               "model": "Damen",
               "producttype": "Tank",
               "status": 1,
               "tax_class_id": 1,
               "visibility": 4,
               "price": 24.99,
               "weight": 0,
               "image": "http://sportokay.dev/skin/frontend/default/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg",
               "name": "Adidas Keyhole Tank Damen Fitnessshirt",
               "description": "Das Adidas Keyhole Tank Damen Fitnessshirt ist ein leichtes, weiches Fitness T-Shirt aus Adidas Climalite Material, welches optimales Feuchtigkeitsmanagement ermöglicht.\r\n- 100 % Polyester\r\n- Adidas Climalite\r\n- Lockere Passform\r\n- Schlitz am Rücken",
               "short_description": "Adidas Keyhole Tank Damen Fitnessshirt",
               "_categories": [
                  "Damen",
                  "Alle",
                  "Fitness",
                  "Fitnessbekleidung",
                  "Shirts"
               ],
               "_prices": {
                  "price": 24.99,
                  "final_price": 24.99,
                  "minimal_price": 24.99,
                  "min_price": 24.99,
                  "max_price": 24.99,
                  "tier_price": null
               },
               "_url": "http://xxx.dev/at_de/adidas-keyhole-tank-damen-fitnessshirt.html"
            }
         }
```

GET /test6_de_idx1/_sear‌​ch?q=brand:xyz does not give results although xyz is synonym to adidas

EDIT2:

This is the mapping currently in use:

```
"test6_de_idx1": {
  "mappings": {
     "product": {
        "_all": {
           "analyzer": "std"
        },
        "properties": {
           "_categories": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
           "_parent_ids": {
              "type": "integer",
              "index": "no",
              "store": true
           },
           "_prices": {
              "properties": {
                 "final_price": {
                    "type": "double"
                 },
                 "max_price": {
                    "type": "double"
                 },
                 "min_price": {
                    "type": "double"
                 },
                 "minimal_price": {
                    "type": "double"
                 },
                 "price": {
                    "type": "double"
                 }
              }
           },
           "_url": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no",
              "store": true
           },
           "adjustment": {
              "type": "string",
              "norms": {
                 "enabled": false
              },
              "index_options": "docs",
              "fields": {
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": {
                       "enabled": false
                    },
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
           "adjustmentrange": {
              "type": "string",
              "norms": {
                 "enabled": false
              },
              "index_options": "docs",
              "fields": {
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": {
                       "enabled": false
                    },
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
           "antennas": {
              "type": "string",
              "norms": {
                 "enabled": false
              },
              "index_options": "docs",
              "fields": {
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": {
                       "enabled": false
                    },
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
           "backlength": {
              "type": "string",
              "norms": {
                 "enabled": false
              },
              "index_options": "docs",
              "fields": {
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": {
                       "enabled": false
                    },
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
           "bike_colour": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                 "prefix": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "text_prefix",
                    "search_analyzer": "std"
                 },
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 },
                 "suffix": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "text_suffix",
                    "search_analyzer": "std"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },....
 "brand": {
              "type": "string",
              "norms": {
                 "enabled": false
              },
              "index_options": "docs",
              "fields": {
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": {
                       "enabled": false
                    },
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
```

EDIT3:

I added the "synonyms" Analyzer to the mapping properties field but it still does not work. Did i do it correct?

```
"brand": {
              "type": "string",
              "norms": {
                 "enabled": false
              },
              "index_options": "docs",
              "fields": {
                 "std": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": {
                       "enabled": false
                    },
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "std"
                 },
                 "synonyms": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "synonyms"
                 }
              },
              "analyzer": "language",
              "include_in_all": true
           },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GET /test6_de_idx1/_sear‌​ch?q=some_field:xyz&s‌​ize=`5 meaning specifically mention the field name in the query (`some_field`). Otherwise it will use `_all` which is not using your analyzer.

`q=xyz` is translated to using `query_string` which, by default, it's using the `_all` field.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i edited the question to show its not working with your hint. Maybe the result for a hit shows more detail.

Comment: Provide the mapping for that index, as well.

Comment: I made a second edit showing the mapping. Now i understand what was meant with "_all" but I dont understand how it should look like to also use the synonym analyzer.

Comment: Use `GET /test6_de_idx1/_mapping` to provide the mapping of the index.

Comment: I provided the mapping you told me to do. Thanks for providing how to do this in the correct way.

Comment: I added it to the bottom...sorry for wasting your time. Its using "std" Analyzer. As i want to extend the behavior i guess i cannot simply add my "synonyms" analyzer. Im really clueless.

Comment: So, if you want your synonyms to be included in the analysis process you can create another subfield for `brand` where you use that analyzer. Or you put the `synonyms` filter inside the list of filter for other analyzers. And if what you only want to use is the "short" version of the queries (`q=brand:xyz`) and nothing like `bool` filters or similar, I think you can use something like `q=brand.*:xyz` meaning looking at `brand` field and all its sub-fields.

Comment: Thank you so much for your current help. I changed the mapping for the brands field as shown in EDIT3, but it still does not work. Did i make a mistake?

Comment: I dont know why adding the synonyms analyzer to the field mapping of each string field did not work as told in EDIT3, but the hint to simply add the synonyms filter to the standard analyzer did the job. Thank you Andrei Stefan, you rock!

Comment: :-) no worries. Just trying to help out.